# How to build the stock Android 4.3 browser from source?

Tags: android, browser, android-source

Similar to [How to build the default browser application in android Os 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894613/how-to-build-the-default-browser-application-in-android-os-4-0), how do you build the stock Android 4.3 Browser app from source?

When I imported a checkout of the source code (https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser) in Eclipse, I could not build it because there are a lot of errors due to reliance on internal and hidden Android APIs. I first tried using Ievgenii Nazaruk's instructions linked to by the other question (http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/), but I get stuck in part 2 because my Nexus 7 (2013) tablet's `framework.jar` does not contain a `classes.dex` entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ievgenii Nazaruk deserves a lot of the credit for figuring out most of this (http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/). I am simply updating his instructions for a Nexus 7 (2013) tablet running Android 4.3, and for the latest version of the [ADT Plugin for Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).*

To get started:

- Make sure that you have Eclipse with the latest ADT Plugin installed as well as the latest Android SDK. At the time of this writing, the latest Android SDK version is 22.3.

  Tip for Mac users: [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) has a package for the Android SDK that can be installed with:
  `brew install android-sdk`
- In Eclipse, open the Android SDK Manager and install the Android 4.3 (API 18) SDK Platform. Also install the Android Support Library under "Extras".
- Attach the Android 4.3 device to your computer using the USB cable and set up [USB debugging](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up) if you have not already done so. Verify that `adb` sees your device by running:
  `adb devices`
- Install [`smali` and `baksmali`](https://code.google.com/p/smali/). At the time of this writing, the current version of `smali`/`baksmali` is 2.0.2.
- Install [`dex2jar`](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/). Homebrew users: `brew install dex2jar`
- Install [`bbe`](http://bbe-.sourceforge.net). Homebrew users: `brew install bbe`

In what follows, I use `$ANDROID_HOME` to refer to the location of the Android SDK.

### Accessing Android's internal/hidden APIs

The `android.jar` in `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18/` is stripped of all internal Android classes and hidden APIs, some of which are needed to build the Browser. We will be following along Ievgenii Nazaruk's instructions to create a custom Android SDK platform which contains all of the internal/hidden APIs.

1. Create a temporary folder and `cd` into it.
2. Create a `framework` folder within the temporary folder and copy `bouncycastle.odex`, `core-junit.odex`, `core.odex`, `ext.odex`, and `framework.odex` from your device's `/system/framework` folder:

   ```
   mkdir framework && cd framework
   adb pull /system/framework/bouncycastle.odex
   adb pull /system/framework/core-junit.odex
   adb pull /system/framework/core.odex
   adb pull /system/framework/ext.odex
   adb pull /system/framework/framework.odex
   cd ..
   ```
3. Use `baksmali` to extract `core.odex`, `ext.odex`, and `framework.odex`:

   ```
   baksmali -a 18 -x framework/core.odex -d framework
   baksmali -a 18 -x framework/ext.odex -d framework
   baksmali -a 18 -x framework/framework.odex -d framework
   ```

   These commands will create an `out/` folder within the temporary folder.
4. We will use `smali` to create a DEX file, but first we need to delete some of the generated SMALI files in the `out/` directory because there are too many for smali to process ("UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: org.jf.util.ExceptionWithContext: Unsigned short value out of range"):

   ```
   rm -rf out/java out/javax/net out/javax/security out/javax/sql out/javax/xml
   smali -a 18 -o android.dex out
   ```
5. Use `dex2jar` to convert `android.dex` to a JAR:

   ```
   d2j-dex2jar android.dex
   ```
6. Now we want to create our custom Android 4.3 platform's `android.jar`. To do this, we'll need some files from the real Android 4.3 platform's `android.jar`:

   ```
   mkdir android_jar && cd android_jar
   unzip $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18/android.jar resources.arsc
   unzip $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18/android.jar 'com/google/common/*'
   unzip $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18/android.jar 'java/*'
   unzip $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18/android.jar 'javax/net/*'
   unzip $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18/android.jar 'javax/security/*'
   unzip $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18/android.jar 'javax/sql/*'
   unzip $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18/android.jar 'javax/xml/*'
   unzip $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18/android.jar 'org/apache/http/*'
   unzip $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18/android.jar 'res/*'
   unzip ../android-dex2jar.jar
   ```
7. To create our custom Android 4.3 platform, we start by copying `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18`:

   ```
   cp -R $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18 $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18-custom
   unlink $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18-custom/android.jar
   jar cf $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18-custom/android.jar *
   ```
8. Open `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-18-custom/build.prop` in a text editor. You need to change two lines:

   ```
   ro.build.version.sdk=-18
   ro.build.version.release=4.3-custom
   ```

   The reason for using ro.build.version.sdk = -18 is because this must be a number and it must be different for each Android SDK platform.

### Checking out the source code

1. Clone the git repo for the Browser source code on GitHub:
   `git clone https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser.git`
2. There are several "android-4.3" tags, but all refer to the same commit: [84e92b9a43097a1252d7311204d2c4ce00c5a78a](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser/tree/84e92b9a43097a1252d7311204d2c4ce00c5a78a)

   Create a local branch from that commit:
   `git checkout -b Nexus_7_2013 tags/android-4.3.1_r1`
3. Import the project in Eclipse. See [How to import existing Android project into Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse)
4. You'll need to [add three missing files](https://github.com/dtrebbien/platform_packages_apps_browser/commit/61e85fe860efa19bc65631538bf2eaaa8b9ee324), [add a <uses-sdk> tag to `AndroidManifest.xml`](https://github.com/dtrebbien/platform_packages_apps_browser/commit/e2af6e34116fc07faf2df040920046e763ae859d), [rename the authority URLs of the Browser's ContentProviders](https://github.com/dtrebbien/platform_packages_apps_browser/commit/29a8b4288677b8629ef1bdf04d5262d622d26e60), and [comment out references to `com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting`](https://github.com/dtrebbien/platform_packages_apps_browser/commit/b234d3ed0631effd5511f0e47055b3960d377dc5). Alternatively, I have a git repo set up which contains these changes: https://github.com/dtrebbien/platform_packages_apps_browser/tree/Nexus_7_2013
5. Add the v4 and v13 Android Support Libraries to the build path. See http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html and [Updated SDK version, getting ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831019/updated-sdk-version-getting-classnotfoundexception-android-support-v4-view-vie)
6. Switch to the custom Android 4.3 platform. Right click on the project in Eclipse and select Properties. Select Android on the left. Check the box next to the "Android 4.3" target having API level -18. That's our custom Android SDK platform that we created in the previous section.

### Removing ADT Plugin's "Forbidden: com/android/internal/**" restriction

I basically followed Ievgenii Nazaruk's instructions in [Part 4](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-4-customizing-adt/), but I found that the modified `AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer.class` file would not work if I added an 'x'. Instead, I changed the 'i' of "internal/**" to a capital 'I'. I also used `bbe` instead of Notepad++:

```
unzip com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_*.jar
mv com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/project/AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer.class com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/project/AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer.class.bak
bbe -e 's~internal/**~Internal/**~' -o com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/project/AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer.class com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/project/AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer.class.bak
jar uf com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_*.jar com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/project/AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer.class
```

### Running

Now for the fun part. Clean the project first, and then Run As -> Android Application. You should now have a fully-functional stock Browser app on your Android 4.3 device!

Comment: If you are going to quote someone, then you should possibly link to the original post :)